# WKWebview, imagePicker does not show a done button when picture chosen

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, wkwebview

As the title suggest, when selecting an image from `WKWebview`, using the Photo Library of the device, the `imagePicker` doesn't seem to register that a photo has been selected.

Below is a picture of it happening

[image]

There isn't much code that goes into this. It's just simply setting up a `WKWebview` and the webview basically takes care of the rest, but instead of showing a "done" button it just continues to show a "cancel" button.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the same issue with this. Hope it will help you.

```
extension UIImagePickerController {
     open override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.custom
     }
}
```